# What kind of vacuum would you achieve if you used a compressor in reverse rated at 8 $\rm bar$? (centrifugal, piston or axial if it matters)

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, vacuum, air

If you used for example a centrifugal compressor that compresses air from an intake of 1bar to 8bar in reverse, what would be the vacuum achieved in mbars? Can a compressor even work with an atmospheric pressure of less than 1atm?

Comment: What do you mean, "in reverse?" Do you mean, if you connect the compressor's inlet to a closed container and then drive the shaft in the "forward" direction? I can't answer, don't know the math, but a centrifugal compressor is not a [positive-displacement pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump#Positive-displacement_pumps): It doesn't _force_ air to move so much as it maintains a pressure difference between its inlet and its outlet. I'm just _guessing_ that the pressure difference probably depends on the density of the air at the inlet, so probably there's some differential equation...